# pandas slicing data frame by column numbers defined in list

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I had data with 12 columns the following would get me those 12 columns.

```
 train_data = np.asarray(pd.read_csv(StringIO(train_data), sep=',', header=None))
 inputs = train_data[:, :12]
```

However, lets say I want a subset of these columns (not all of them).

If I had a list

```
a=[1,5,7,10]
```

is there a smart way I can pass "a" so that I get a new dataframe whose columns will reflect the entries of "a" i.e first column of new data frame is the first column of the big dataframe, then next column in the new dataframe is the 5th column in the big dataframe, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,a]`...

Comment: wow kudos on replying in literally 30 seconds.